# How to create more than one drop zones while drag enter using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to generate more than one drop zones on a page while using a drag and drop a field or an element to the container? For example, if I have a container that will generate dynamically top, left, right, and bottom drop zones when a field is dropping on it. So I can have option to format my fields like rows and columns wise.  Like this [Demo page](https://www.planso.de/planso-forms/). I would like to store those field styles/settings into the database.

Anyone come across something like this?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just use a class as dropzone selector
(code based on https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ )

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 70px; height: 70px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; border: 1px solid #000000}
  .droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #555555 }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    $(".droppable").droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // detect which dropzone the object was dropped into
        var index =  $(".droppable").index(this);
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped in box with index: " + index);
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div class="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
<div class="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>no, Drop here</p>
</div>
<div class="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>rather, Drop here</p>
</div>
<div class="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>you should really Drop here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```